# Jenkins - Download File to user's browser as a post-build step

Tags: jenkins

I am running a powershell script as a Build step in a Jenkins job which is generating an output file in the workspace. I am trying to add a step which would then automatically download the file to the user's browser. Is this possible?

Comment: I would think that it isn't possible. The user don't need to even have to have the browser open on Jenkins for it to perform a build. Maybe an automatic email or just copy to a shared folder will do.

Comment: Yes Those seem to be the only viable options at the moment. Thanks